# Ionic Error building android: WebViewer@~0.0.1 is not in the npm registry

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, apk, cordova-plugins

I get this error below when I try to build the ionic for android.
Command used: `ionic cordova build android`

Log error

```
Discovered saved plugin "WebViewer". Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "WebViewer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin WebViewer@~0.0.1 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/WebViewer - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'WebViewer@~0.0.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/regisoliver/.npm/_logs/2020-06-03T06_36_20_816Z-debug.log
config file undefined requested for changes not found at /home/regisoliver/Documentos/Desenvolvimento/imob/platforms/android/undefined, ignoring
```

config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.2" />
<plugin name="WebViewer" spec="~0.0.1" />
```

does anyone have a solution on how I can build ?